# VPS overload problem

Tags: vps

I am hosting my site  with HOSGATOR LEVE 3 VPS,my site is based on drupal with static page cache enabled and has 60000 posts and only have 5000 PV/day ,however the vps CPU usage is often overload. Is it my website's problem or VPS' problem?

```
CPU
1.13 GHZ
RAM
768 MB
Disk Space
30 GB
Bandwidth
500 GB
```

5000pv/day, est 60000 posts mysql, static boost cache enabled.

Comment: What does `top` say during these periods?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is:  it depends.  You should be able to pull up some performance stats on your VPS to see if there are specific processes that are using more CPU than others.

If you have both your database and web server running on the same machine, it is possible that they are competing for resources.  If your database is not optimized and is running inefficient queries (or is having to process a lot of data) it may be using a lot of CPU.

SSL could also play a factor if you have large amounts of data that has to be encrypted before being sent to the user (this can be CPU intensive as well depending on traffic levels).

The first thing you should check is which process is using the most CPU and track it back from there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it my website's problem or VPS problem?

I'm assuming you mean do you need to optimise your site or need a more powerful VPS.
Otherwise I don't know what you would mean by a "problem" with the VPS. Not getting the CPU or ram advertised, unlikely. A problem with the hardware, that would affect many many customers, unlikely. A flaw in the original software configuration, again unlikely.

Where have you seen high CPU usage and is it actually affecting your sites?
You should run top (or better htop) and see which process is sing the CPU resources. It's possible you will see (most likely perl) scripts you don't recognise, in which case reimage the server and recover from backups (you do have backups?)

If there are no rogue processes then next look at your log files for errors. If there are no serious errors or unwanted access such as rogue bots spidering your site then you should consider a more powerful server.

Answer (score 0):

The resources of the VPS are not optimized and the VPS itself is not tweaked for the better performance.

You will have to monitor the processes as well as resources usages on the server. Check if there are any slow mysql queries etc.. . It really depends on how the server is configured and optimized.